# how to automate principal component analysis and show on a web page, is it possible?

Tags: automation, web-deployment, pca

I have result of Dimension reduction using principal component method and I want to show that result on web portal by just making a web page where user select the variable and do analysis. I have ipynb file which is juypter notebook file. any solutions for this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the solution of this---

1. First convert ipnyb file to py file and read that file in python environment
   and run the file.
2. Output comes up
3. get http response by using http web client api.
4. Now Read the output data in any language you are comfort with. as I Read this
   using asp .net and python engine and made web portal using this file.